# How to update multiple columns having the same value or different values in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-update

I want to update multiple columns in a table having the same value. For example if we consider this table.

```
col1     col2
--------------
2        -99
-99        5
3          6
4        -99
```

I want to update -99 values in the table to NULL and the expected result looks like this.

```
col1     col2
--------------
2        NULL
NULL        5
3           6
4        NULL
```

I am using this way.

```
update table_name set col1 = null where col1 = -99;
update table_name set col2 = null where col2 = -99;
```

Or what if I want to update columns on unique conditions.
For example -99 with null in column1 and 5 with null in column2.

Is there a way to achieve this in a single statement ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: Whats the advantage of a single statement?

Comment: SQL Server <> MySQL - please stop adding conflicting tags... add the tag for the actual RDBMS you are using only.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: @DaleK I didn't know this etiquette. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can, by using a case expression, but whats the advantage?

```
update table_name set
  col1 = case when col1 = -99 then null /* or any new value for col1 */ else col1 end
  , col2 = case when col2 = -99 then null /* or any new value for col2 */ else col2 end
where col1 = -99 or col2 = -99;
```

Note, as pointed out by Larnu, when you are setting the column to null you can simplify the update to:

```
update table_name set
  col1 = nullif(col1,-99)
  , col2 = nullif(col2,-99)
where col1 = -99 or col2 = -99;
```

And you can change the values you are using (-99) on a per column basis to whatever you want e.g. `col2 = 5`

```
update table_name set
  col1 = nullif(col1,-99)
  , col2 = nullif(col2,5)
where col1 = -99 or col2 = 5;
```

Comment: But what if i need to substitute NULL for different values for different columns. For example I want to substitute -99 with null in column1 and 5 with null in column2 ??

Comment: 1) Thats not what you asked in your question. 2) Why do you want to combine unrelated updates? 3) You should be able to just substitute the values in the statement I provided with the values you want. 4) Please tell us what RDMS you are using (instead of tagging multiple).

Comment: An even more succinct method would be `NULLIF` (at least for SQL Server).

Comment: @DaleK 1. changed my question. 2. why can't we combine two unique update conditions? 3. yes I was able to but what if different conditions are required ( modified my question ) 4. I'm using SQL. Thanks for removing the other tags

Comment: @SakethNaidu SQL is not a RDBMS... maybe you mean SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

You can use NULLIF.

```
UPDATE null_table
SET co1 = NULLIF(col1,-99)
,col2 = NULLIF(col2,-99)
```